# Postgres does not save changes on refresh

Tags: node.js, postgresql, psql, nodemon, postgresql-9.5

I'm still in the process of learning, I'm attempting to build a fullstack app and I'm facing a little issue.

Even after making changes to the database after the request, refreshing the page on the frontend doesn't preserve the changes.

This is how I'm handling my post requests

```
app.post('/api/data', (req, res) => {
        handlePost(req.body.index, req.body.formulaString) // runs asynchronously, and runs the query for making the changes
            .then(() => {
                client.query('SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY id ASC')
                    .then((x) => {
                        res.send(x.rows)//the response works exactly as intended, the frontend gives the correct values etc.
                  })
            })
    })
```

Although if I just restart the server, all the changes are saved and preserved even after I refresh the frontend.

Comment: What is `client`? Where does it come from, what else are you doing with it? Please show the entire database-handling code, as well as your `handlePost` implementation that does make the changes to the database.

Comment: Re `client`: You can take a quick look at the [pg package docs](https://node-postgres.com/) that should clarify this.

`handlePost()` does indeed run queries to make changes to the db.

Comment: No, I know the docs. You need to [edit] your question to include the code that defines `client` so that we can see where and how you are opening and closing the connection. Same for the `handlePost` implementation. My guess is that you're making multiple independent connections, which would explain the strange behaviour, but you need to post more code so that I'm able to verify this and suggest an appropriate solution.

Answer (score 0):

I would add a `.catch((error) => { console.log(error) });` to your promise handling and see if it doesn't clue you in.

Comment: There should be an unhandled rejection warning/exception if there was a promise error

Comment: Thanks for the response! Sadly (or luckily xD) tho there are no errors and the issue persists. 
@bergi